# Is there a way i can use datetime to convert a string to milliseconds without using timedelta?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I'm trying to convert a string containing a time ("%H:%M:%S.%f") to an int of the equivalent milliseconds. The complication is, the time is the output from FFmpeg, it's a point in the audio file. I need to get the number of milliseconds the time in the string represents. The timestamp method in DateTime is milliseconds from epoche, without another time stamp from when I began, this is no good.

For example:
t = "00:05:52.654321"
should be converted to:
i = 352654321

What is the best way to accomplish this?

This is how I figured out to do it.

```
def _convert_string_to_int(self, s) -> int:
    begin = datetime.datetime(1900,1,1)
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, self._ffmpeg_format_string)
    return int((end - begin).total_seconds() * 1000000)
```

It just feels really unnecessary to use timedelta like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since timestamps are relative to the Unix Epoch (`1970-01-01`) you can make a `datetime` object from your time by prepending that date to it and then getting the timestamp of the resultant object to get the time string converted to seconds . Since python timestamps are floating point representations of seconds since the epoch, you will need to multiply by 1000 and convert to integer to get the number of milliseconds:

```
from datetime import datetime

t = "00:05:52.654321"
d = datetime.strptime('1970-01-01 ' + t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print(int(d.timestamp()*1000))
```

Output:

```
352654
```

If you actually want microseconds, multiply by `1000000` instead.

As an alternative, you can split the time string on `:` and sum the parts, multiplying by `60` or `3600` to convert the hour and minute parts to seconds:

```
t = "00:05:52.654321"

millisecs = int(sum([float(v) * 1000 * 60 ** (2 - i) for i, v in enumerate(t.split(':'))]))
print(millisecs)
```

Output:

```
352654
```

Again, if you want microseconds, just multiply by `1000000` instead of `1000`.

Answer (score 0):

A number of milliseconds is inherently a time *interval*, so there is good reason why `datetime.timedelta` instances have a `total_seconds` method while `datetime.datetime`, `datetime.date` and `datetime.time` do not have one.

In principle you could use `datetime.datetime.time(end)` to get an object with properties including `hour`, `minute`, `second` and `microsecond`, and then use these to construct an arithmetic expression for the elapsed time since midnight on the same day. However, the supported way to handle time intervals like this is precisely the timedelta approach that you are already using.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I suppose the next question would be is there a module more suited for my situation than datetime? Thanks again for the response!